# Light signals in the courtship and mating

Tags: zoology, ethology, communication

I am investigating on the emission of signals in the courtship and mating in the animals.

I know that the fireflies emit light signals as a courtship ritual.

Are there other animals that use this phenomenon of luminescence?

Answer (score 1):

Many [Ostracods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostracod) (esp. the [Cyprididae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyprididae)) use bioluminescence to attract mates. The [Bermuda fireworm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odontosyllis_enopla) (a polychete worm) also uses bioluminescence to attract mates.

If you have not yet, you should definitely have a look at [wikipedia > Bioluminescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bioluminescence)